# Nginx signed integers, CVE-2013-2028

Tags: c++, security, nginx

I have just came across this particular analysis post about the security bug a few years back, CVE-2013-2028, by [vnsecurity](http://www.vnsecurity.net/research/2013/05/21/analysis-of-nginx-cve-2013-2028.html).

However, the first point interested me, saying that the bug was essentially caused by an integer sign mismatch.

> It simply parses the chunked size input as hex and convert it to base of 10. And since ctx->size is defined with size_t, an unsigned type, the value of the variable can be misinterpreted as negative number when casting to signed type, as we will see later.

As I was curious about this, I went to search for the `struct` of 'ctx' and I came across this:

```
struct ngx_http_chunked_s {
ngx_uint_t           state;
off_t                size;
off_t                length;
};
```

As far as I know, `ctx-> size` is not of `size_t` but `off_t`, which is a signed integer. So, may I know if I got this wrong or that it was rephrased wrongly.

The older nginx version can be found in this [repo](https://github.com/kitctf/nginxpwn/).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick reading I think that the writer was a little bit confused between the`ngx_http_read_discarded_request_body`'s local `size` and `ctx->size`.

The path of the input is:

1. [`ngx_http_parse_chunked:2011`](https://github.com/danghvu/nginx-1.4.0/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_parse.c#L2011): `ctx->size` is a signed input.
2. [`ngx_http_parse_chunked:2183`](https://github.com/danghvu/nginx-1.4.0/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_parse.c#L2183): signed `ctx->length` set according to `ctx->size`.
3. [`ngx_http_discard_request_body_filter:735`](https://github.com/danghvu/nginx-1.4.0/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L735): signed `r->headers_in.content_length_n` set to `ctx->length`.
4. [`ngx_http_read_discarded_request_body:649`](https://github.com/danghvu/nginx-1.4.0/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L649): `r->headers_in.content_length_n` will be converted to `size_t` and assigned to `size` (if `content_length_n < NGX_HTTP_DISCARD_BUFFER_SIZE`, which will be always true if `0 > content_length_n`).
5. [`ngx_http_read_discarded_request_body:652`](https://github.com/danghvu/nginx-1.4.0/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L652): `r->connection->recv` is called with its `size` as a number of bytes to read.
6. `ngx_http_read_discarded_request_body`: `size > sizeof (buffer)` (`NGX_HTTP_DISCARD_BUFFER_SIZE`). Therefore, a stack overflow will occur.

I hope it is understandable.

Comment: Hey I think this is the correct answer and the writer got it a little wrong.